# The operator of exponential derivative applied in quotients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory

I have an other question for a function different to the example given before in the link below:
[Exponential derivative operator and continuous functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405078/exponential-derivative-operator-and-continuous-functions/405092#405092)
We define for instance a function as:
$$H(y)=\frac{1}{y^{-n}(d/dy)^{-n}e^{-(d/dy)y(d/dy)}T(y)}$$
where $T$ is not an operator but a function and $n$ is an integer. What can we say about the function and the operator? Is it possible to have
$$H(y)=e^{(d/dy)y(d/dy)}(d/dy)^{n}y^{n}\frac{1}{T(y)}?$$

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really defined $(d/dy)^{-1} $, but let's pick, for instance, $(d/dy)^{-1} f(y) = \int_{0}^{y} dy' f(y')$. Then, your two expressions for $H(y)$ in general are not equal. A simple counterexample is the case $T(y)=y$. In this case,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{y^{-n} (d/dy)^{-n} e^{-(d/dy)y(d/dy)} T(y)} &=& \frac{1}{y^{-n} (d/dy)^{-n} (y-1)} \\
&=& \frac{1}{y^{-n} (y^{n+1}/(n+1)! -y^n /n!)} \\
&=& \frac{(n+1)!}{y-(n+1)}
\end{eqnarray}
but
$$
e^{(d/dy)y(d/dy)} (d/dy)^{n} y^n \frac{1}{T(y)} = e^{(d/dy)y(d/dy)} (d/dy)^{n} y^{n-1} =0
$$

Comment: The question seemed to be "Is it possible to have …", which I interpreted to mean whether the equality *ever* holds, as opposed to whether the equality *always* holds.  But perhaps @AdamHammam can make it clearer which interpretation was meant.

Comment: @LSpice - the questions by AdamHammam tend to concentrate on the effect of the operator, I haven't seen any that concentrate on the function being acted on (here, $T$) in terms of being a solution to a kind of generalized differential equation. I think what is meant is "could $H$ possibly be simplified into the form ...". But yes, AdamHammam should clarify.